# How can I keep a navigation link highlighted on selection in Vue.js

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

So, I have a navigation bar with router-links. What I want is for the selected link to remain highlighted on selection, so that the users know which page they are on. Currently I have something like this.

```
<div class="mynav">
    <router-link to="...">...</router-link>
    ....
</div>

...

.mynav {
 ...
}

.mynav a {
 ...
}

.mynav a:hover {
 ...
}
```

I tried to use `.mynav a:active`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this style to the style tag inside the Vue component:

```
<style lang="css">
    .router-link-exact-active {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #123456;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

in /router/index.js:

```
export default new Router({
  linkExactActiveClass: 'is-active', // this is important
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/main',
      name: 'Main',
      component: Main
    },
```

then router-link should looks like this:

```
<router-link class="nav-link pl-0" to="/main">Main</router-link>
```

and then in CSS for example:

```
.router-link-active {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to be defining your  tag with more arguments. See https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class for details.

So for your example:
`<router-link to="..." active-class="active" ></router-link>`

Alternatively, you could alter where you configure the router:

```
export default new Router({
  ...,
  linkExactActiveClass: 'is-active',
  routes: []
})
```

See https://forum.vuejs.org/t/add-and-remove-is-active-class-v-for-router-links/24859 for more details.